# Can not copy row data to a dataframe in pandas while iterating a dataframe row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe into which data is to be filled from another dataframe's column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'account_number' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
 'id_value' : [101,101,201,201,301,301]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['node1','node2','relation'])

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if (index % 2 == 0):
        out['node1'] = row['account_number']
    else:
        out['node2'] = row['account_number']
        out['relation'] = 'SELF'

out
```

I am trying to achieve :

```
node1    node2    relation
  1        2       SELF
  3        4       SELF
  5        6       SELF
```

I don't seem to understand the flaw in my code. When I print the values row[account_number] they get printed correct but when I copy them to my result dataframe they don't get copied.

I am pretty much new to python, pandas and even stack overflow, please excuse me for bad code or anything I have violated.

Comment: you're trying to append data into one row of the output that come from two rows of the input. Somehow you need to handle that relationship. Is the second node always right after the first node as it is in your example?

Comment: Yes it is right after the first node. They all are in pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning values to an empty data frame's column, which according to broadcasting, will do nothing, because it is empty initially.

```
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['node1','node2','relation'])
out['node1'] = 1
out
# node1 node2   relation
```

You can provide a row index to avoid this:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if (index % 2 == 0):
        out.loc[index//2, 'node1'] = row['account_number']
    else:
        out.loc[index//2, 'node2'] = row['account_number']
        out.loc[index//2, 'relation'] = 'SELF'
​
out
#node1  node2   relation
#0   1      2       SELF
#1   3      4       SELF
#2   5      6       SELF
```